# How to record video with VLC in my C# app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, video-streaming, vlc, vlc.dotnet

I am making a streaming app  in c# and I have embedded the vlc player using vlc.dotnet.

How can I add the feature to allow the user to record the livestreaming with a press of a button for example.

And how can I view the seek bar as the livestreaming goes on?

Thank you!

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlc.DotNet is archived, and you're expected to use LibVLCSharp instead.

Recording "on-the-fly" is not yet possible with libvlc (and thus not with LibVLCSharp nor Vlc.DotNet). It is a feature that is only possible with VLC, but you can start a second stream and pass it the same recording options as the CLI.

Have a look at the ["How do I?" section](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/3.x/docs/how_do_I_do_X.md#how-do-i-record-a-media-to-the-file-system)

To view the "seek bar", you have to implement it yourself, you have properties that give you the time, duration and position plus events that lets you know when Time/Position changed.